# Youtube.Search.list fetches empty pages

Tags: google-apps-script, youtube, youtube-api

I'm trying to get all short videos during the day from youtube api via google script.
Here is the script that I use to achive that:

```
function test_get_all_videos() {
  var res, part, params, count, page_token;
  part = 'snippet';
  params = {maxResults: 50, 
            q: 'machine learning',
            type: 'video', 
            videoDuration:'short', 
            publishedAfter:  '2018-02-01T00:00:00Z', 
            publishedBefore: '2018-02-02T00:00:00Z', 
            };
  res = YouTube.Search.list(part, params);
  Logger.log(res.pageInfo.totalResults);
  Logger.log(res.items.length);
  count = res.items.length;
  while (res.nextPageToken){
    page_token = res.nextPageToken;
    params.pageToken = page_token;
    res = YouTube.Search.list(part, params);
    Logger.log(page_token + ': ' + res.items.length);
    count += res.items.length;
  }
  Logger.log(count);
}
```

even taking in account that totalResult is a approximation
[image]
I expect that pages must contain exact information for items.
But instead I get huge discrepancy and a pages with zero items:
[image]

For some dates there are a lot of pages with zero items.
Is it something that I'm missing or it is a bug here?

Comment: What happens if you use the Youtube API try-it, not Apps Script?

Comment: I did the same using UrlFetchApp and api key with the same result https://youtu.be/wd5Hr1LSRfM, so I posted an issue in bug tracker