# YouTube Search.list: big 'totalResults' property and no items in response

Tags: search, youtube-data-api

I'm a novice user of YouTube Data API. Am interested in the method `Search.list` and tried it as follows:

```
curl \
  'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&maxResults=50&publishedAfter=2020-01-01T00%3A00%3A00Z&publishedBefore=2020-01-01T00%3A01%3A00Z&q=Nemo&type=video&key=[YOUR_API_KEY]' \
  --header 'Authorization: Bearer [YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN]' \
  --header 'Accept: application/json' \
  --compressed
```

The JSON response provided was:

```
{
  "kind": "youtube#searchListResponse",
  "etag": "r_b6korptu_RtbUGCZrdsQokN6M",
  "nextPageToken": "CDIQAA",
  "regionCode": "RU",
  "pageInfo": {
    "totalResults": 263644,
    "resultsPerPage": 50
  },
  "items": []
}
```

I'm wondering about how could the value of `totalResults` be `263644` when there are no items in the result set?

Is it possible that between the dates of `2020-01-01T00:00:00Z` and `2020-01-01T00:01:00Z` a number of `263644` videos related to the search key `Nemo` were published?

[A similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48715980/youtube-search-list-fetches-empty-pages) was asked on this forum, yet, upon years having passed, no answer emerged.

Answer (score 1):

First thing to acknowledge is that the property `totalResults` is not reliable by its very specification (the emphasis below is mine):

> [**pageInfo.totalResults**](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list#pageInfo.totalResults) (integer)
>
> The total number of results in the result set. *Please note that the value is an approximation and may not represent an exact value.* In addition, the maximum value is 1,000,000.
>
> You should not use this value to create pagination links. Instead, use the `nextPageToken` and `prevPageToken` property values to determine whether to show pagination links.

This peculiarity of `totalResults` was already mentioned within the question you quoted above and [is also confirmed officially](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/155088389#comment2) by Google's staff.

To confirm myself the statement emphasized above, I did call `Search.list` on your very same URL and obtained the following JSON response:

```
{
  "kind": "youtube#searchListResponse",
  "etag": "nR1UCL5Kru9VxHzZ2DnocjjIfjk",
  "nextPageToken": "CDIQAA",
  "regionCode": "...",
  "pageInfo": {
    "totalResults": 268418,
    "resultsPerPage": 50
  },
  "items": []
}
```

Moreover, repeating the same API call several times in a row (only seconds apart one from another), I never got the same value of `totalResults`, yet always got an empty `items` array.

There's only one thing to learn from here: *between the two date-time values (`2020-01-01T00:00:00Z` and `2020-01-01T00:01:00Z`), there's no video that matches the query term `Nemo`*.

If only changing `publishedBefore` to `2020-01-01T01:00:00Z` -- thus using the following URL:

`https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&maxResults=50&publishedAfter=2020-01-01T00%3A00%3A00Z&publishedBefore=2020-01-01T01%3A00%3A00Z&q=Nemo&type=video&key=...`

for invoking the same endpoint --, the JSON response obtained contains an `items` array of only one element:

```
{
  "kind": "youtube#searchListResponse",
  "etag": "w5YKbVnLAwAFSmESM0ZoCCtvHo0",
  "nextPageToken": "CDIQAA",
  "regionCode": "...",
  "pageInfo": {
    "totalResults": 255015,
    "resultsPerPage": 50
  },
  "items": [
    {
      "kind": "youtube#searchResult",
      "etag": "qoMGew0LKTvIT7PdH6o7vJ8Ob9s",
      "id": {
        "kind": "youtube#video",
        "videoId": "YU2sbTlAxLk"
      },
      "snippet": {
        "publishedAt": "2020-01-01T00:33:51Z",
        "channelId": "UCgMTHBAZjC6mkq257UseEzQ",
        "title": "YANDA ZAKA NEMO NAMBOBIN WAYAR KA DA SU KA BACE",
        "description": "Ta yanda zaka nemo Lambobinka da suka Bace ================================== Ga link din da zaku shiga ...",
        "thumbnails": {
          ...
        },
        "channelTitle": "kk Techtube",
        "liveBroadcastContent": "none",
        "publishTime": "2020-01-01T00:33:51Z"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

If `publishedBefore` is set to `2020-01-01T00:34:00Z`, then the result set is identical with the one above.

These tests *seem to indicate* that `Search.list` works OK w.r.t. the issue you have risen.