# YouTube Data API: check if an user subscribed to me

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I can't seem to see in the docs if there is a way, given an user ID, if that user follows my channel or not.

I saw this API:

`https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/subscriptions/list?apix_params=%7B%22part%22%3A%5B%22snippet%2CcontentDetails%22%5D%2C%22mine%22%3Atrue%7D`

but that seems to only list my subscriptions. Unless I misconfigured it.

Is this even possible?

Comment: Perhaps what you are looking for is [Members](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/members) of the channel.

Answer (score 1):

Querying [`Subscriptions.list`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/subscriptions/list) with `mine=true` will return the list of channels to which you -- the authenticated user -- subscribed.

For the other way around -- i.e. for a list of channels that are subscribers of your channel -- there are two other request parameters: [`myRecentSubscribers`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/subscriptions/list#myRecentSubscribers) and [`mySubscribers`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/subscriptions/list#mySubscribers).

Comment: I tried that however I got this returned: `"pageInfo": { "totalResults": 99, ...` - However I have about 150 followers not 99. So I assumed it was not was I was looking for.

Comment: Unfortunately `totalResults` is *totally unreliable* (see [this answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64299044/8327971)). I never take it into account, irrespective of API endpoint.